# ASP.NET MVC5 routing/rendering slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am facing a rendering/routing performance issue with the following scenario:

There's 2x2 Windows Server 2012 machines (2 machines in a testing environment, 2 in production).
The web app runs fine in testing but in production it gets extremely slow after logging in, while performing the a redirect to the actual welcome page.

We couldn't figure out any hard-/software differences between both environments. Network performance seems well, too. (Other ASP.NET applications work well on all machines involved)

What happens is:

1. Navigate to login screen (renders ok)
2. Enter credentials and login
3. From here it takes up to 40 minutes for the welcome page to show up (worst case, avg somewhere between 6 and 12 minutes)
4. Further navigation works ok again

The login process itself doesn't break anything and (including license checks) performs ok within a second.

Using log messages the actual bottleneck has been tracked down to be somewhere inbetween the Redirect and the Welcome page's action being called:

```
Logger.LogDebug("Redirecting to /Home/Welcome");
return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
```

...

```
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
    Logger.LogDebug("Routed to /Home/Welcome");
```

...

As this actual waiting happens even before the page is actually being rendered (since this happens at the end of the Welcome action, I'm a bit lost on how to continue debugging / figuring out, what slows down the process.

Is there anything to enable inside of the IIS to get more info on what is happening?
Any kind of event inside of the MVC routing I might be able to attach to?

Comment: You'll have to use some timers or do some profiling to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey integrated Glimpse for profiliing, which didn't help as it only showed the very same results as the logging?

Comment: Where is your production system hosted?

Comment: It's hosted locally on an ESX VM

Comment: Are you using a version of ASP.NET MVC that has source code available?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203921/discussion-between-revoluzifer-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Like other comments indicated, you need a good enough profiler which might reveal more information. IIS failed request tracing and ASP.NET ETW tracing can also be helpful, to help you narrow down and locate the spot that consumes most of the time. But you are still far from the culprit at this moment, and this question cannot be answered yet.

Comment: To troubleshooting this kind of issue, we need to figure out which event is costing so much time. First of all, you need to trace the performance with fiddler. So we would know the low performance come from network level or server level. If this issue come from server node, then you may enable failed request tracing for the long time taken. It will tell us which process cost most of time. If asp.net pipeline take longest time, then you need to capture hang dump and check the call stack. It would probably help you find root cause.

Comment: Thank you guys, especially @JokiesDing, will check fiddler and see about the dump as well :)